# Some variables of Window object are missing when called onload

Tags: javascript, onload

This [simple fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4x3Tx/2/) shows properties of Window object:

```js
var obj = this; // object Window
var variables = "";
for (var name in obj) {
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
        variables += name + " : " + obj[name] + "<br/>";
    }
}
document.writeln(variables);
```

When this script is called [directly with no wrap](http://jsfiddle.net/4x3Tx/1/) it shows this result:

```
window : [object Window]
document : [object HTMLDocument]
InstallTrigger : [object Object]
obj : [object Window]
variables : window : [object Window]  document : [object HTMLDocument]  InstallTrigger : [object Object] obj : [object Window]
name : name
getInterface : function getInterface() { [native code] }
location : http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/
navigator : [object Navigator]
```

But when [called onload](http://jsfiddle.net/4x3Tx/2/) it shows only:

```
window : [object Window]
document : [object HTMLDocument]
InstallTrigger : [object Object]
getInterface : function getInterface() { [native code] }
location : http://fiddle.jshell.net/4x3Tx/2/show/
navigator : [object Navigator]
```

And so the question is obvious: can somebody explain why are `obj`, `variables` and `name` variables missing from the second fiddle results? In both cases the `obj` refers to Window object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you run the code "onLoad", it is put inside a function and assigned to `window.onload`:

```
window.onload=function(){
    var obj = this;
    var variables = "";
    for (var name in obj) {
        if (obj.hasOwnProperty(name)) {
            variables += name + " : " + obj[name] + "<br/>";
        }
    }
    document.writeln(variables);
    console.log(obj);
}
```

`obj`, `variables` and `name` are now local to that function, not global and hence are not properties of the `window` object.

Answer (score 2):

The function scope, in which your code is executed, changes.

**Scenario One** *(script called in global scope)*:

Script has access to variables/arguments defined in it's current scope (`obj`, `variables` and `name` in your case.

**Scenario Two** *(script is executed from the handler of an onload event)*:

The same holds as in Scenario One except that the scope changes to the function inside the event handler. Thus, the aforementioned locals aren't in scope.